# declaration of C function 'void msgBox(const char*, const char*)' conflicts with previous declaration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, overloading

I get the error: **delcaration of C function 'void msgBox(const char*, const char*)' conflicts with previous declaration 'void msgBox(const char*)' here** in my DLL, being compiled in MinGW. Why isn't it accepting my declarations?

```
#include <windows.h>

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"
{

void DLL_EXPORT msgBox(const char* msgText);
void DLL_EXPORT msgBox(const char* msgText, const char* msgTitle);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal to have two functions with the same name that have C language linkage.

7.5p6

> At most one function with a particular name can have C language
>   linkage.

Comment: Hmm, since I'm linking it with a C++ program, would it be safe to completely remove the *extern "C"* part?

Comment: @MonetR.Adams: If you use only C++ and it is the same compiler, then you don't need `extern "C"`.

Comment: So, no *extern "C"* is needed while compiling, or in the header? Right?

Comment: @MonetR.Adams: If your dll and application are C++ built with the same compiler, then there is no problem. Problems occur when calling the function from C code or some other language, or when using different C++ compilers.